# Recursive javascript exceeding call stack size

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an angularjs controller that's is polling for stuff. The polling function calls itself with a timeout. Below are two examples of this. The first exceeds the call stack size, but the second example does not. Why is that?

Example 1 (Exceeds call stack size):

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.value = 1;
    function poll() {
        $scope.value++;
        $timeout(poll(), 1000);
    }
   poll();
});
```

Example 2 (works fine):

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.value = 1;
    function poll(){
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.value++;
            poll();
        }, 1000);
    };     
   poll();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not passing the function but its returned value (`undefined`). Which means you immediately call it and as it calls itself, well, here's your stack overflow.

Change

```
$timeout(poll(), 1000);
```

to

```
$timeout(poll, 1000);
```

As an aside, you can rewrite

```
function poll() {
    $scope.value++;
    $timeout(poll, 1000);
}
poll();
```

in a slightly more elegant manner which doesn't pollute the external scope :

```
(function poll() {
    $scope.value++;
    $timeout(poll, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put function in side $timeout(): Sou make it like:

```
$timeout(function(){

   pool();
   // You can also add some other things here...

}, 1000):
```